# Calculate $I_m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2m}}$ using complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come as far as deducing that the denominator can be written as a geometric series. Hence, for $m=2$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-x}{1-x^5} dx &= 2 \pi i ( B_1 + B_2 ) - \int_{C_R} \frac{1-z}{1-z^5} dz \\
&= 2 \pi i \left( \frac{1 - \exp(i \frac{2 \pi}{5})}{-5 \exp(i\frac{8 \pi}{5})} + \frac{1 - \exp(i \frac{4 \pi}{5})}{-5 \exp(i\frac{16 \pi}{5})} \right) - 0\\
&\overset{*}{=} \frac{\pi}{5} \cot\left( \frac{\pi}{10} \right) \sec \left( \frac{\pi}{5} \right).
\end{align*}
where $B_1$ and $B_2$ denote the residues in the upper-half plane.

However, I can't work out why the equality $\overset{*}{=}$ should hold. I'm sure it's the result of some clever manipulation but I've been staring at it for a while without much progress. Is my solution wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a tiny error in the last step, otherwise your solution is perfect.

You have that
\begin{align}
2\pi i \left(\frac{1-e^{i2\pi/5}}{-5e^{i8\pi/5}}+ \frac{1-e^{i4\pi/5}}{-5e^{i16\pi/5}} \right)
& = -\frac{2\pi i}{5}\left(e^{-i8\pi/5} - e^{-i6\pi/5} + e^{-i16\pi/5} - e^{-i12\pi/5}\right)\\
& = -\frac{2\pi i}{5}\left(e^{i2\pi/5} - e^{i4\pi/5} + e^{i4\pi/5} - e^{-i2\pi/5}\right)\\
& = \frac{4\pi}{5}\frac{e^{i2\pi/5} - e^{-i2\pi/5}}{2i}\\
& = \frac{4\pi}{5} \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right).
\end{align}

Comment: How do you get from $\left(e^{-i8\pi/5} - e^{-i6\pi/5} + e^{-i16\pi/5} - e^{-i12\pi/5}\right)$ to $\left(e^{i2\pi/5} - e^{i4\pi/5} + e^{i4\pi/5} - e^{-i2\pi/5}\right)$?

Comment: For example, $e^{-8\pi/5} = e^{-i8\pi/5 + i2\pi} = e^{i2\pi/5}$.

Comment: Lightbulb moment. Of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over 1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots + x^{2m}}}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 - x \over 1 - x^{2m + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 - x \over 1 - x^{2m + 1}} + {1 + x \over 1 + x^{2m + 1}}}\,\dd x
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - x^{2m + 2} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=2\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{2m + 2} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{1}^{0}{1 - x^{-2m - 2} \over 1 - x^{-4m - 2}}
\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm]&=2\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{2m + 2} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{0}^{1}{x^{2m - 2} - x^{4m} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=2\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{2m + 2} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{4m} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x
- \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{2m - 2} \over 1 - x^{4m + 2}}\,\dd x}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> However,
>   \begin{align}&\dsc{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu} \over 1 - x^{\nu}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\mu/\nu} \over 1 - x}\,{1 \over \nu}\,x^{1/\nu - 1}\dd x
> ={1 \over \nu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{1/\nu - 1} - x^{\pars{\mu - \nu + 1}/\nu}
> \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over \nu}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\pars{\mu - \nu + 1}/\nu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> -\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{1/\nu - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over \nu}\braces{\Psi\pars{1 + {\mu - \nu + 1 \over \nu}}
> -\Psi\pars{1 + \bracks{{1 \over \nu} - 1}}}
> =\dsc{{1 \over \nu}\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1 \over \nu}
> -\Psi\pars{1 \over \nu}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Expression $\pars{1}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over 1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots + x^{2m}}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2m + 1}\braces{%
\bracks{\Psi\pars{2m + 3 \over 4m + 2} -\Psi\pars{2m - 1 \over 4m + 2}}+ \bracks{\Psi\pars{4m + 1 \over 4m + 2} - \Psi\pars{1 \over 4m + 2}}}
\end{align}

> With
>   [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{1 - z} - \Psi\pars{z} = \pi\cot\pars{\pi z}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over 1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots + x^{2m}}}
={\pi \over 2m + 1}\bracks{%
\cot\pars{{2m - 1 \over 4m + 2}\,\pi} + \cot\pars{{1 \over 4m + 2}\,\pi}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2m + 1}\bracks{\cot\pars{\pi \over 4m + 2} + \tan\pars{\pi \over 2m + 1}}}\,,\qquad m = 1,2,3,\ldots
\end{align}

> For $\ds{m = 2}$ the result becomes:
>   $$
> {\pi \over 5}\bracks{\cot\pars{\pi \over 10} + \tan\pars{\pi \over 5}}
> ={\root{10 + 2\root{5}} \over 5}\,\pi \approx {\tt 2.3903}
> $$